# to service response context or not

Tags: wcf, soa

when calling a state changing service e.g.

```
void SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
```

the following may happen

1. the parameters are invalid
2. an exception occurs
3. authorisation is not successful
4. a business rule(s) is violated
5. everything is ok

For conditions 1-3 I think the service should return an appropriate exception
For #4 I also think the service should return an exception but some believe it should return an object that reflects the success or otherwise of the call (a response object).

In our case a business rule violation is an opportunity for an end user to choose an alternative action. I think a custom exception that lists error codes can be parsed by a client and localised. A response object can  do the same but in a more strongly typed way.

With a response object we need to cater for a path back up the stack to the service (if(ok) etc) and we can't rely on an exception unwiniding a transaction.

Is either of these options an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 1):

There is also third approach not mentioned by your listing. The approach is called expected exception. Request-response operations in web services offers definition of three types of messages:

- Input = request. Can be defined only once for each operation.
- Output = successful response. Can be defined only once for each operation.
- Fault = expected unsuccessful response. You can have zero or more faults defined for each operation.

When using faults you tell client that the operation can fail due to some well defined reason. For example incomplete customer definition and client can handle this fault in different way than common unexpected SOAP fault.

In WCF expected faults are handled through `FaultContract` and generic `FaultException<>`. Check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx) and its subarticles for introduction to fault handling.

The implementation of error handling is mostly up to you. Returning custom object is especially helpful in complex scenarios where the operation can succeed only partially and you must report both success and parts which failed.